# BCM4313 cannot see 802.11n 5GHz SSID

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I'm using 17.04 and the wireless is working fine with broadcom-sta (installed by default with proprietary driver). But I found it is not connected to 5GHz SSID, which is different than 2.4Ghz. I use iwlist wlp2s0 channel and it does show 32 channels in total, and the frequencies include 5.X GHz. I also forced my WiFi AP 5G channel to the supported channels listed by iwlist command. But anyway, my laptop always cannot see my 5GHz SSID. Is there any setting or configuration I need to change for 5GHz wifi connection? Thanks.

Update 1: Here is the result of lspci -nnk

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0587]
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Update 2: After issuing `apt-get purge broadcom-sta-dmks`, the Kernel can also uses brcmsmac (bcma) for WiFi. With this driver, I can only see 2.4GHz channels in `iwlist` command. So definitely this cannot support 5GHz channels.

Comment: How did you install broadcom-wl?

Comment: Sorry, I think it is Broadcom-sta driver, which is installed by default by enabling proprietary drivers. I thought it was Broadcom-wl when `lsmod` command lists "wl".

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in whatever is responsible for listing available frequencies.

I clearly remember that I did not have 5GHz with this exact BCM4313 (`14e4:4727`) but today we were testing 5GHz and I noticed it was listed as available. But in the official list [here](https://www.broadcom.com/products/wireless/wireless-lan-bluetooth/bcm4313#documentation) it's listed as supporting 2.4GHz only:

```
4313 2.4 Ghz        0x14e4  0x4727
```